# Is it still impossible to get rid of out of PermgenSpace exceptions when redeploying?

Tags: java, jvm, permgen

This is an old problem I've always had. I want to redeploy in development environment. After some deployments I run out of permgen and have to kill the server. Years ago I tried to find a solution to the problem but just found Spring and Hibernate blaming each other for the problem. Has any solution been found?

Spring Roo claims it doesn't generate classes at runtime so it wouldn't be a problem. Does it really work and if it does, how can I configure my application like that?

I realize there are two questions here but if you can answer one it is enough :)

Comment: just increase permspace of your server

Comment: Yes this has always been the "solution", which I'm not satisfied with. It does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running your application under linux, running your application with the IBM JRE will solve this issue.

Comment: Does the IBM JRE support Java 6? Seems like they only support up to 1.5

Comment: yes it does : see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/linux/download.html

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand it, typical PermGen storage leaks go like this.

1. Somewhere there is a reachable reference to some object whose class has been replaced by a hot deployment.
2. That object has a reference to its Class descriptor.
3. The Class descriptor has a reference to its ClassLoader.
4. The ClassLoader has references to the Class descriptors for all classes that it has loaded.
5. Each Class descriptors has references to the classes statics frame, its bytecodes, its native code, and so on.

Just one reference to one object is sufficient to cause the permgen leak.  If could be an enum value, a listener that hasn't been unregistered, ...

**EDIT**

The normal approach taken by people who encounter this problem is to shrug their shoulders and increase the PermGen heap size.  If you really need to fix the problem for your web application(s), then:

- Look at the way that your webapp shuts down, making sure that database connections / connection pools are closed, all callbacks are unregistered, etc.
- Use a Java memory profiler to trace the PermGen (and other) memory leaks triggered by a redeployment.
- Be prepared to repeat the process if new leaks are introduced as your webapp evolves.

I don't know if there are specific issues with Hibernate, but any complicated framework is potentially susceptible to this kind of problem, either on its own or in combination with application code.

Comment: Do you know if this always happens when using Hibernate, or it's a mistake I might have made? Is there a way to detect these kind of leaks?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that can help with this some. Spring has a "IntrospectionCleanupListener" that can help a little. If you are loading and creating JDBC connections within the web app you can have a servlet context listener that will deregister the drivers you loaded in the app. These help, but do not entirely fix the problem.